# plotting in for loop with R using package eHOF

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I want to run a number (~100) of eHOF models using the R package eHOF, produce the graphs that this package can make of the models, and save jpeg files of each one. I am trying to use a for loop to accomplish this quickly, but I am not able to get it to make the graphs. I don't see anything in the R studio plots window, and I produce jpeg files that have nothing in them (as an aside problem, I am not producing the names for the jpeg files correctly in the loop).

To produce these plots, outside a loop there is no problem, if for example I call my model modSP<-HOF(Sp, ...) then using plot(ModSp) produces the desired graph. But within the loop, nothing is produced, and I get several error messages of the sort:

```
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In plot.window(...) : "boxp" is not a graphical parameter
3: In plot.window(...) : "las.h" is not a graphical parameter
4: In plot.window(...) : "onlybest" is not a graphical parameter
5: In plot.window(...) : "para" is not a graphical parameter
```

Background: I am using  R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) in R studio, and package eHOF in windows 7.

My code is as follows:

```
species<- read.csv("F:/Thesis_projects/Chapter4_climateChange/HOF/259species.csv")
species<-as.data.frame(species)
enviro<-read.csv("F:/Thesis_projects/Chapter4_climateChange/HOF/EnvironmentalData.csv")
enviro<-as.data.frame(enviro)
species_enviro<-merge(enviro, species, all.x=FALSE)
HOF_Sp<-species_enviro[,23:25]
GDD<-species_enviro[,19]
library(eHOF)

SpeciesCodes<-c("ACPE","ACRU2","ACSP2")
Modx<-NULL
for (Spp in seq_along(SpeciesCodes)){

  Modx[[Spp]]<-HOF(HOF_Sp[[Spp]],GDD, M=1,family=binomial, bootstrap=2, freq.limit = 100)

  jpeg(filename = (paste(("GDD_responsecurve_",SpeciesCodes[[Spp]],".jpg"),sep="")),
     width =8.3, height = 8.3, units = "cm", pointsize = 8, bg="white", res = 800)

  print(plot((paste(c(Modx[[Spp]]))), boxp = TRUE,
    las.h = 1, onlybest = TRUE, para = TRUE,
    gam.se = FALSE, newdata = NULL, lwd=1, leg = TRUE, add=FALSE, 
    xlabel="Growing degree days", ylab="Probability"))

   dev.off()
                                    }
```

My Data looks like this:

```
> head(GDD)
[1] 996.1681 996.1681 962.0662 962.0662 945.7007 945.7007
```

(there are lots of 1's in the species data too, just not in the first few rows).

```
   > head(HOF_Sp)
      ACMI2 ACPA ACPE
    1     0    0    0
    2     0    0    0
    3     0    0    0
    4     0    0    0
    5     0    0    0
    6     0    0    0
```

Any advice at all would be very appreciated! I think it is an issue with the plot function in the loop being mistaken for the generic plot function of R. If I didn't provide enough information, I will be happy to edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things going on here:

1. Your `SpeciesCodes` vector has codes different from the column names in `HOF_Sp`.
2. `seq_along(...)` returns the index of each element in it's argument, not the element itself.
3. The `plot` method for `HOF` is invoked when an object of class `HOF` is passed to `plot(...)`. But you are passing `paste(c(HOF))` which is incomprehensible...
4. Your example is not reproducible because it does not run with the data you provided (did you try to run it??). Specifically, the sample of `HOF_Sp` is degenerate because there are no non-zero values.

It's impossible for me to test this code because of (4) above, but try this:

```
SpeciesCodes <- c("ACPE","ACRU2","ACSP2")
for (Spp in SpeciesCodes) {
  model <- HOF(HOF_Sp[[Spp]],GDD, M=1,family=binomial, bootstrap=2, freq.limit = 100)
  jpeg(filename = (paste(("GDD_responsecurve_",Spp,".jpg"),sep="")),
       width =8.3, height = 8.3, units = "cm", pointsize = 8, bg="white", res = 800)  
  plot(model, boxp = TRUE,
       las.h = 1, onlybest = TRUE, para = TRUE,
       gam.se = FALSE, newdata = NULL, lwd=1, leg = TRUE, add=FALSE, 
       xlabel="Growing degree days", ylab="Probability")
  dev.off()
}
```

Note that this invokes the vector version of `HOF(...)`, which I gather is what you want.

This does not solve the problem in (1) above (species codes do not match columns names), but other than that it should work.

Comment: hallelujah! This works, except I edited the code a little bit, so now:SpeciesCodes<-c("ACMI2", "ACPA", "ACPE")
for (Spp in SpeciesCodes) {
  model <- HOF(HOF_Sp[[Spp]],GDD, M=1,family=binomial, bootstrap=2, freq.limit = 100)
  jpeg(filename = (paste("GDD_responsecurve_",Spp,".jpg")),
       width =8.3, height = 8.3, units = "cm", pointsize = 8, bg="white", res = 800)  
    plot(model, boxp = TRUE,
       las.h = 1, onlybest = TRUE, para = TRUE,
       gam.se = FALSE, newdata = NULL, lwd=1, leg = TRUE, add=FALSE, 
       xlabel="Growing degree days", ylab="Probability")
    dev.off()
}